# Difference between Angular 2 versions while referring 'angular2/angular2'

Tags: angular

In the starter application for angular 2 following script tag is mentioned to reference the library

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.26/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

I tried to use version **.46** instead of **.26**. But the application threw following error:

[image]

However interestingly when I changed back the angular 2 version to **.26** (as mentioned in starter example) the app started to work fine. My code in main.ts file is :

```
    /**
 * Created by ojaved on 11/12/2015.
 */
import {Component,View,bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2'
@Component({
    selector:'my-app'
})

@View({
    template:'<h1>My first angular 2 app</h1>'
})

class AppComponent{

}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

And when I use angular 2 version **.46** then it marks the following line as error :

[image]

Please can somebody explain what's the difference between these versions of angular 2 and how can I successfully refer latest version in my apps? Many Thanks.

Regards,
Omer Javed

Comment: That's pretty old, why don't you stick to the [latest documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)?

Comment: @EricMartinez Not sure how did I end up to the older page. Thanks for pointing in right direction !